# typescript initialize object with partial object literal

Tags: typescript, object-literal

I want to initialize an instance of a class with an object literal not containing all the elements in the class but whose elements are in the class.

```
class ATest{
    aStr:string;
    aNum:number;

    result(){return this.aStr + this.aNum;}
}
let test=new ATest;

test={aStr:"hello",aNum:12};   // error, result() is missing in the object literal
```

What is the way to do that assignment exploiting the most of the validations of ts?

```
test=Object.assign(test,{aStr:"hello",aNom:12});
```

would work but then you miss the validation of the input fields - see aNom that's wrong but gets in

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have an object literal, an instance of a class must be created using `new ClassName()`

The simplest solution is to add a constructor accepting a `Partial<T>`

```
class ATest{
    aStr:string;
    aNum:number;
    constructor(obj: Partial<ATest>) {
        Object.assign(this, obj);
    }
    result(){return this.aStr + this.aNum;}
 }

 let test=new ATest({aStr:"hello",aNum:12});
```

Inside this new constructor you can do validations of the fields as required.

Comment: Yes, but the validations would be at runtime. I was looking for a solution detecting at compile time if that's possible...

Comment: @Joan, The `Partial<T>` is validated at compile time. It forces you to specify members of `T` with the same type. I thought you wanted some extra validations, such as weather `aNum >0` or the like. Do you want all the members to be mandatory ?

Comment: Oh, I was totally unaware of the Partial<> thing!

Comment: Thanks! 
I see that this would not work on a non-literal object:

let prms={aStr:"hello",aXXXXNum:12};
let test=new ATest(prms);

lets it pass without warning... or I'm missing something?

Comment: @Joan no unfortunately that is true, this is not due to partial though, excess properties on object literals are only checked on assignment of a literal to a variable. So `let prms: Partial<ATest>={aStr:"hello",aXXXXNum:12}; let test=new ATest(prms); ` is invalid, but your example is valid. Type checks still occur so you can't pass `let prms={aStr:"hello",aNum:'12'}; let test=new ATest(prms);`

Comment: yes, what you suggest     let prms:Partial<ATest>={aStr:"hello",aXXXXNum:12}; seems to be the way to go. Thank you again.